# How do I get the currentPlayTime of an ObjectAnimator while it is playing?

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

This is my ObjectAnimator:

```
public void startSimulateProgressAnimator() {
    simulateProgressAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "currentProgress", 0, 100).setDuration(2000);
    simulateProgressAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    simulateProgressAnimator.start();
}
```

During the 2 seconds that it is playing, I want to get the currentPlayTime so that I can find the percentage completion of the animation by saying:

```
(simulateProgressAnimator.getCurrentPlayTime() / 2000) * 100
```

Just to put this into context, the ObjectAnimator draws a circle on the screen and I want to put a percentage in the centre of the circle to show the user how many percent of the circle has been drawn.

I looked for ObjectAnimator listeners but there is nothing that would listener while an animation is running: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=listen+objectanimator&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

These are the only listeners available:

```
onAnimationCancel(Animator animation)
onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation)
onAnimationStart(Animator animation)
```

Comment: do that inside `setCurrentProgress(float f)` method

Comment: But in this case, the animation is actually simulated and I'm not setting current progress.

Comment: what do you mean? do you have setCurrentProgress? if so, when it is called?

Comment: The setCurrentProgress method is there to set the currentProgress of a download / upload in the real world. This is simulated progress - we are saying we are drawing the circle over two seconds programmatically. Where would you even setcurrentprogress?

Comment: no, `setCurrentProgress` is called by `simulateProgressAnimator` because it uses `currentProgress` property: if you use `xxx` property then `setXxx` will be called

Comment: Oh - you mean do it inside getCurrentProgress? If the value of currentprogress is being animated, that means I can determine the value of the progress by getCurrentProgress after the animation has started?

Comment: use `xxx` property or whatever and do what you want from its `setXxx` method

Comment: Ah - I see, I have tested this and it is working. Do you want to convert our discussion to an answer and I will accept?

Comment: good, you could also use `ofFloat(T target, Property<T, Float> property, float... values)` but `String` property is much easier